# How to locate or find nvm(node verison manager )file

Tags: nvm

I'm trying to find the location of `nvm` file.
I want to remove it, and I want to reinstall it.
I have faced a problem with finding the location of `nvm` file

```
logos1056@logos1056-Vostro-3578:~$ nvm ls
            N/A
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)

logos1056@logos1056-Vostro-3578:~$ rmdir $NVM_DIR

rmdir: failed to remove '/home/logos1056/.nvm': Directory not empty

logos1056@logos1056-Vostro-3578:~$ /home/logos1056/.nvm

bash: /home/logos1056/.nvm: Is a directory

logos1056@logos1056-Vostro-3578:~$ cd /home/logos1056/.nvm

logos1056@logos1056-Vostro-3578:~/.nvm$ rmdir $NVM_DIR

rmdir: failed to remove '/home/logos1056/.nvm': Directory not empty
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

nvm is usually installed in your home directory within a hidden folder called `.nvm`.

`$NVM_DIR` is the environment variable that contains the path to nvm.

You want to remove the directory and all its content. You can do it this way.

```
$ rm -rf $NVM_DIR
```

Then you can [install nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation-and-update) again.

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner,

```
rm -rf $NVM_DIR ~/.npm ~/.bower
```